# Displaying file content as Title on main page, instead of FileName

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, isolatedstorage

I want to create an app where you have a main page that show all the notes, you can create a new note or select a note from the list.

Right now, it is showing all filename such as Sample1.txt, Sample2.txt.

I want it to show like this:

---

### This is awesome app.

### Remind me to buy milk

Not like this:

---

### Sample1.txt

### Sample2.txt

### Sample3.txt

### Sample4.txt

Here's the code to display the list:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) 
    { 
        using (var store = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) 
        { 
            this.NotesListBox.ItemsSource = store.GetFileNames(); 
        } 
    }
```

And here's the binding on main xaml

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="NotesListBox" SelectionChanged="Notes_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

I would love to know this.. Thanks!

Comment: Where would that text come from? Is it stored in a note?

Comment: It is store in each text files in Isolated Storage.

Comment: Where would the title come from though? Text files are just text data. There's not a "title" unless you've introduced one as part of your file format.

Comment: i want the title from the first line of the note itself from a file

Answer (score 0):

The very quick and very dirty solution would be to replace

```
this.NotesListBox.ItemsSource = store.GetFileNames();
```

with

```
var filesNames = store.GetFileNames();
var titles = new List<string>();
foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, isf)))
    {
        titles.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    }
}
this.NotesListBox.ItemsSource = titles;
```

This way your listbox will list the first lines of all your files.

The problem with this solution however is that you have a link between the items in the listbox en the files. A better solution would be to introduce a model for your notes e.g.:

```
public class Note
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

You can use this model to load all notes and put it in the listbox like this:

```
// put this in your view class
private List<Note> _notes;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) 
{ 
    _notes = new List<Note>();
    var filesNames = store.GetFileNames();
    foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, isf)))
        {
            var note = new Note();
            note.FileName = fileName;
            note.Title = sr.ReadLine();
            note.Body = sr.ReadToEnd();
            _notes.Add(note);
        }
    }
    this.NotesListBox.ItemsSource = _notes;
}
```

In your xaml you need to replace

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
```

with

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Title}"/>
```

In your `SelectionChanged` handler you can now refer to the notes like so:

```
private void Notes_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Note note in e.AddedItems)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(note.Body);
    }
}
```

An even better solution would be to use [mvvm](/questions/tagged/mvvm). But may be that's too far stretched for now.

Good luck!

Comment: Okay, I will try that and get back with you tonight. Thanks!

Comment: This is how I save, filename and body

using (var store = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())

    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(tbxFilename.Text, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store))
    {
      StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
      writer.Write(tbxNote.Text);
      writer.Close();
    }